# Como filtrar datos especificos de una coleción de AngularFireDatabase

Tags: angular, firebase

Necesito filtrar unos datos específicos obtenidos desde la base de datos y no se como hacerlo. He buscado documentación sobre esto en firebase, pero no me queda claro.

como puedo filtrar con parámetros... como podría hacer esto por favor. o si conocen de alguna documentación para aprender de ello.

Hasta el momento en el servicio tengo este código:

```
public ordersDB: AngularFireList;

constructor(private firestore: AngularFireDatabase) {

      this.ordersDB = this.firestore.list('ordenes');

    }


 getFilterData(){

    return this.ordersDB.snapshotChanges().pipe(

      map((changes) => {
        return changes.map((c) => ({
          $key: c.payload.key,
          ...c.payload.exportVal(),
        }));
      })

    );

  }
```

y en typescript lo recibo de esta forma:

```
this.ordersService.getFilterData()
            .subscribe(resp =>{

    console.log('resp', resp)


});
```

con esto consigo respuesta de todos los datos. pero quiero aprender a filtrarlos.

Comment: Esta es la documentación para las consultas con firestore https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries si ya la habías revisado y tienes dudas puedes agregar los ejemplos de lo que has intentado y los problemas que tienes.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione... tuve que hacerlo de esta manera:

```
getFilterData(orderBy:string, equalTo:string): Observable<OrdersModel[]>{    
    return this.http.get<OrdersModel[]>(`${this.api}ordenes.json?orderBy="${orderBy}"&equalTo="${equalTo}"&print=pretty`);    
}
```